# Proving russian roulette survival statistics

Tags: probability

Russian Roulette is a game where you essentially put a gun to your head. The gun can hold M number of bullets, but only one bullet has been loaded. That is, there is a 1/M chance of shooting yourself when you fire the gun for the first time.
After you have fired the gun, if you're still alive, you now know that the first chamber was empty. Hence, the chances for you to die if you shoot yourself for a second time are 1/M-1.

Now, let's suppose that the gun has been fired n-1 times so far. I came up with the following equation to deduce the probability of surviving the shot. Clearly, since the gun has been shot n-1 times so far, it must now be the nth iteration for the gun to fire.

I reasoned that the probability for survival is the probability that the gun has not yet been fired, and does not fire this time either, or that the gun already fired in the past and hence has no more bullets.

I came up with a general formula for the chances of survival for m slots with one bullet:
$\frac{(m-1)!}{(m-1-n)!}\frac{(m-n)!}{m!}+\frac{n-1}{6}$

The problem is, how can i prove this formula? I tried to do a proof by induction, and while proving the base case is obviously easy, i don't see how i could prove this true for n+1 given that it is true for n.

Comment: $m$ slots with one bullet, what is $n$? Without telling us what $n$ is, the question cannot be answered because it is unclear.

Comment: @5xum N is the current turn. Another way to express n would be to say that n is one plus the number of times the trigger has been pulled so far.

Comment: What is a "turn"? Please, make your question self contained. We don't like to play the "guess what I want to ask, then answer it" game on this site. Describe, precisely, how the game is played, and what probability you are looking for. And don't do it in a comment, *edit* your question to fill in all the details.

Comment: What is a slot?

Comment: @5xum I'm not sure how to do that. In my consideration, a turn is simply the step of the iteration from 1 to m. The first player must shoot himself, and n is the step of the iteration. That is, the gun has been fired n-1 times before this person picked up the gun to shoot himself.

Comment: Vital information must be added *to your question*. Not in comments.

Comment: Why is your formula not $\frac{(m-1)!}{(m-1-n)!}\frac{(m-n)!}{m!} \frac{1}{m-n}$ ?

Comment: @AayushAgrawal Just describe the game so that if you describe it to a person who never heard of russian roulette, he would still be able to play it. For example, what in the world is "the iteration"?

Comment: @AayushAgrawal Also, as I said before, **edit** your question, don't put vital information into comments.

Comment: @Justpassingby Every gun has a particular number of bullets it can hold in the chamber. Usually that number is 6, but it can also vary. M is the number of possible places where the bullet can be.

Comment: @5xum Okay, i'll edit the question to describe the game.

Comment: @AayushAgrawal Thank you. And try to imagine someone who you do not know is reading the question for the first time, then ask yourself "can he understand it"? Make sure no concept is referenced *before it is defined*. Currently, you are using words like "the iteration", and the number "n", and nobody knows what they are.

Comment: @5xum question edited, please tell me if i should make any further changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized the mistake i was making.

The probability for surviving the gun shot is the probability of the bullet not firing earlier and not firing this time either plus the probability of the bullet having fired earlier (Since there was only one bullet, this makes the current shot safe).

But that is simply $1 - \frac{1}{6}$ since if the bullet is not loaded in the n-th slot of the gun, you will survive. Hence, the large formula is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: You see? Once you slowly and methodically ask your question, the answer often becomes clear.